# NextJS assetPrefix and basePath prefix not taking effect

Tags: next.js

I'm unsuccessfully attempting to create a simple NextJS site that has a `/app` prefix on all the links. So that on the home page (which has a link to `/about`), the About link should end up as `/app/about`.

(updated based on comments below) My `next.config.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  assetPrefix: "/app",
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    basePath: "/app",
  },
  basePath: "/app",
};
```

And my `package.json`'s scripts section has:

```
    "build": "next build && next export",
```

However, when I copy the contents of the generated `out` folder into my web server, the index page's "About" link always points to `/about` without the desired prefix. What could be causing that? It appears as though the `assetPrefix` value is working:

[image]

So it's just the root `basePath` field that isn't working.

Comment: According to nextjs documentation you should setup module.exports = {
  basePath: '/app',
}, not under publicRuntimeConfig. Page that uses publicRuntimeConfig must have getInitialProps or it won't be available.

Comment: @zoranjeremic I tweaked the next.config.js so it looks [like this](https://pastebin.com/7CVzrAUF) with that root `basePath` field, still running into the same results though. Additionally, to confirm it's a NextJS issue (and not something to do with the server this app is hosted on), when I directly open the `index.html` file generated in the `out` folder, it links to `file:///about`, while I'd expect it to be `file://app/about`

Comment: Try to use experimental.basePath instead. Also, try to use latest canary release 9.5.2-canary.18 of nextjs. There are some reports this was fixed recently  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/9872

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for bringing that canary release to my attention. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported as fixed recently. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/9872

Try to use the most recent canary release. At this moment it's **9.5.2-canary.18**